# Using REST API to request data from Python script

Tags: python, apache, rest, api, request

I have a python script in Apache server, and inside this script there are many types of data. 
I want to request those data using REST API.
How can I do it ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Flask! Here's some documentation: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#routing

Basically, you can define your routes through Flask so you can return specific data for specific endpoints that you create.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try to use Flask:

```
from flask import Flask from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__) api = Api(app)

class HelloWorld(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {'hello': 'world'}

api.add_resource(HelloWorld, '/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Please answer in English!

Comment: For more information: https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html